# How to manually uninstall VMware Workstation 9 on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 PC?

Tags: uninstallation

I was trying to update VMware workstation v9 to v9.0.3. After downloading the update, the program attempted to uninstall current version but failed as it couldn't find uninstall.exe. I checked Programs and Features but don't see VMware Workstation listed. Looks like I need to manually uninstall it. Is there a process/ command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this rather comprehensive knowledge base article from VMWare: 
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1308

Comment: That's great - please add a separate answer or a comment describing what fix worked so other users can find your solution too. Also please remember to upvote answers and assisting answers. Welcome to the community.